# Promise being resolved before the beginning of test

Tags: node.js, promise, mocha.js, nedb

**Solution**

`Converting the promises into the promise factory` fixes the issue of logs appearing before the test runs. And my promise.all was not resolving because `I just assumed` that the NeDB database initialization function follows the callback pattern without `properly going through the documentation`. After looking again at the documentation, I understood that it does not. removing the callback from the promise factories fixed the issue.

**Problem**

I have a promise chain in which a `Promise`, if resolved, returns a `Promise.all`. The `Promise.all` takes in 3 promises. Here is my code:

```
lib.init = (dir) => {
  // check if the .data directory exists
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(dir) lib.baseDir = path.join(__dirname, '../', dir)
    console.log('DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: working directory - ', lib.baseDir)
    fs.stat(lib.baseDir, (error, stats) => {
      if(!error){
        console.log('DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: successfully retrieved file stats.')
        if(!stats.isDirectory()) {
          console.log('DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: the base directory does not exist. Creating base directory now.')
          fs.mkdir(lib.baseDir, (err) => {
            if(!err) {
              console.log('DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: base directory created successfully.')
              resolve()
            } else reject('Could not create the data directory.')
          })
        } else resolve()
      } else {
        console.log('DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: could not retrieve file stats. Creating base directory now.')
        fs.mkdir(lib.baseDir, (err) => {
          if(!err) {
            console.log('DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: base directory created successfully.')
            resolve()
          } else reject('Could not create the data directory.')
        })
      }
    })
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: initializing databases.')
    return Promise.all([loadComponents, loadShows, loadScreens])
  })
}
```

Here are the 3 promises which are passed as arguments:

```
const loadShows = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // for saving profiles (set of screens designed/configured for different shows)
  console.log('DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: initializing SHOWS collection.')
  lib.shows = new Datastore({ filename: path.join(lib.baseDir, 'shows.db'), autoload: true }, error => {
    if(!error) {
      console.log('DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: successfully initialized SHOWS collection.')
      resolve()
    } else reject(`Could not load shows. Error: ${error.message}`)
  })
})

const loadScreens = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // for saving screen settings (list of component settings)
  console.log('DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: initializing SCREENS collection.')
  lib.screens = new Datastore({ filename: path.join(lib.baseDir, 'screens.db'), autoload: true }, error => {
    if(!error) {
      console.log('DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: successfully initialized SCREENS collection.')
      resolve()
    } else reject(`Could not load screens. Error: ${error.message}`)
  })
})

const loadComponents = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // for saving components (default settings for each component)
  console.log('DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: initializing COMPONENTS collection.')
  lib.components = new Datastore({ filename: path.join(lib.baseDir, 'components.db'), autoload: true }, error => {
    if(!error) {
      console.log('DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: successfully initialized COMPONENTS collection.')
      resolve()
    } else reject(`Could not load components. Error: ${error.message}`)
  })
})
```

Here is my test file:

```
let chai = require('chai')
let chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised')
chai.use(chaiAsPromised).should()

let _data = require('../lib/data')

describe('data library', () => {
  describe('#init', () => {
    it('should be able to initialize the collections without error', () => {
      return _data.init('testData').should.be.fulfilled
    })
  })

  after(function () {
    // runs once after the last test in this block
    // delete the testData directory and its contents
    return _data.cleanup()
  });
})
```

Here is the log that I get when I run `mocha`:

```
yarn workspace v1.22.4
yarn run v1.22.4
$ mocha
DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: initializing SHOWS collection.
DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: initializing SCREENS collection.
DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: initializing COMPONENTS collection.


  data library
    #init
DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: working directory -  /home/nm/projects/nightmoves/local-data/testData
DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: could not retrieve file stats. Creating base directory now.
DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: base directory created successfully.
DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: initializing databases.
      1) should be able to initialize the collections without error
DATA LIBRARY CLEANUP: removing everything in -  /home/nm/projects/nightmoves/local-data/testData
DATA LIBRARY INITIALIZATION: cleanup successful.


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) data library
       #init
         should be able to initialize the collections without error:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/home/nm/projects/nightmoves/local-data/test/data.js)
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
```

What I don't get is why am I seeing the logs from Promises passed in the promise.all even before the test is run by mocha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR.

1. Node.js executes all statements of modules you load/require.
2. Promises are executed immediately, not only if someone is interested in their result.

So your second snippet, which reads:

```
const loadShows = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

}
const loadXXX = ...
```

just creates these promises and executes immediately at the start of program (or at least when module is `require`d or `import`-ed).

Then mocha and other code is executed and eventually calls `init` which waits for `Promise.all(...your promises)` and at this point of time they are probably fulfilled given they fulfill fast.

To solve this, either change your functions to "promise factories":

```
const loadShows = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

}
const loadXXX = () => ...
```

and then use them like this:

```
return Promise.all([loadShows(), ...])
```

Or move their declarations to `.then` handler in your `init` method. They will be instantiated and executed only when you reach this place of code.

Comment: Converting promises to factories fixed the logs issue. I tried increasing the timeout but it was no help as my code was incorrect. I assumed that the NeDB initialization function accepted a callback. So removing the callback from the promise factories fixed everything else.